# Deduce Generalized/Simplified Centerline of Polygon

Tags: postgis

I am trying to simplify or generalize this line so that I can hopefully measure the distance of it to the edge of the polygon.

```
select ST_ApproximateMedialAxis(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON(((-80.8412658987022 34.1660342350919,-80.8201493961777 34.1491732039802,-80.7938808799986 34.12803101412,-80.7823648804348 34.1189215104194,-80.8057216013707 34.1096698850572,-80.8085726483091 34.1085450840884,-80.8162581465962 34.105509838908,-80.8211978779797 34.1035497638106,-80.8292288463342 34.1003709481608,-80.8425934383365 34.0950793552281,-80.8488600510505 34.0925981823603,-80.8544316901703 34.0904030820366,-80.8660369492458 34.0857832997596,-80.8725926310451 34.0831825548311,-80.8777673193063 34.0811366331491,-80.8799088560089 34.0802778039775,-80.8814288127895 34.0795488962646,-80.8825349258461 34.0789097408919,-80.8841593217952 34.0778456063897,-80.8872233335899 34.0758038278844,-80.8900012926255 34.0739446738077,-80.897237734234 34.069129438273,-80.9170364547685 34.056088914272,-80.9233798147266 34.0518328214276,-80.9589876455634 34.0005659006958,-80.9593286909663 33.9992747332424,-80.9593232455713 33.9980875292162,-80.95903093443 33.9971771679919,-80.9582694838496 33.9961186731383,-80.9574881420641 33.9963534951178,-80.956071381589 33.9952036093591,-80.9553339680881 33.9945617488257,-80.9542166359889 33.9941956626997,-80.9517446074277 33.9943146367112,-80.950434075772 33.9936278910144,-80.9496166720717 33.9940813192975,-80.9487269925566 33.9941072170745,-80.9471242396918 33.9940054318053,-80.9437627960162 33.994202731371,-80.9333074829539 33.9800447385739,-80.9312213858582 33.9811037892085,-80.9292938788094 33.9784843752537,-80.9278668822508 33.9790090100578,-80.9217366427318 33.9831578731374,-80.9156305850834 33.9804846887175,-80.8917689235969 33.9852930983978,-80.8888150769542 33.986044240949,-80.8700665451349 33.9912332320281,-80.8667507240666 33.9918903756404,-80.8652523716996 33.9921127599959,-80.8480957900886 33.9944627802332,-80.8360872219477 33.9961109992233,-80.8261089506675 33.9974817620737,-80.8215321011255 33.9981058600974,-80.7876588727588 34.002731558115,-80.7673417110511 34.0054695108093,-80.7601880727213 34.0058614578401,-80.7493734337369 34.0063544032332,-80.7336989474484 34.0070619880204,-80.704396348013 34.0085408466828,-80.7692542983472 33.9429794151679,-80.9116020414011 33.867921845217,-80.9894689018683 33.9013856185515,-80.9930736121574 33.9040598875538,-81.017055075931 33.9082508083282,-81.0240373115726 33.9097980280566,-81.029741172617 33.913355710098,-81.0295267355704 33.915741948732,-81.0270997072856 33.9171085423254,-81.0240430060798 33.9178735416307,-81.0186827436137 33.9219198999834,-81.0172394486416 33.9249858192402,-81.0171901406125 33.9299906246677,-81.0189027366719 33.9359493481839,-81.0245594219797 33.942871766319,-81.0366139328867 33.9648331666174,-81.0366184223023 33.9648411849728,-81.0384921148192 33.9678884747734,-81.0459491871052 33.9768622258111,-81.0461012049066 33.9829504723864,-81.0461347640081 33.9838757506654,-81.0466600229417 33.9859354904306,-81.0478320563043 33.9856118828822,-81.0507695199973 33.9932366733339,-81.0534531032781 33.9953760318784,-81.0550758076024 33.9962148934027,-81.0560200948515 33.999731653593,-81.0551526924428 33.9962474416661,-81.0566682731223 33.9969041733889,-81.0583267228 33.998392673683,-81.0597167599205 33.9985767316309,-81.0607464333012 33.9991928877416,-81.0620299583159 34.0013109800178,-81.0617027921501 34.0028428609094,-81.0640005419914 34.0048723070114,-81.0670184347529 34.006947362231,-81.0675656686207 34.0081458086822,-81.0696006914187 34.0072782309057,-81.0708077578717 34.0061390641665,-81.0732391451704 34.0060016387646,-81.075645544806 34.0067990919046,-81.0770560549929 34.0078848281224,-81.0795287787301 34.0097881973675,-81.081173696309 34.0104256907931,-81.0839985172178 34.0117437380831,-81.0835417083831 34.0128216951651,-81.0849497652194 34.01306671096,-81.0863879520423 34.0133687743495,-81.0873517204055 34.0135540203019,-81.0892947857258 34.0132590147917,-81.0908027239665 34.0138395469576,-81.0929649927402 34.0145347480802,-81.0952380471981 34.0158521604489,-81.0976224179402 34.0173862959409,-81.0996737967083 34.0202445734284,-81.0998347168986 34.0227674118866,-81.1017703169466 34.0242696421303,-81.1034896462302 34.023688326655,-81.1061553069218 34.0238237420721,-81.1109854154445 34.0241546386257,-81.1170802243728 34.024292665674,-81.1201282030541 34.0247684942706,-81.1232328219372 34.0246218310327,-81.1283399135561 34.0257081697962,-81.1365844043468 34.0281829017196,-81.1449001187455 34.03175208609,-81.1517803316969 34.0334138857423,-81.1580916290254 34.0372231873003,-81.161329371853 34.0421367034461,-81.1680718761161 34.045311053962,-81.1730129987508 34.0469847921145,-81.1831174359209 34.0469704128543,-81.1853414899178 34.0455797767853,-81.1875853586773 34.0453458910001,-81.1903435389232 34.0460393393441,-81.1897647172678 34.0526924276135,-81.1905044033555 34.0460803520267,-81.1948549322093 34.0481572823327,-81.1986437544057 34.0483903173593,-81.2011856845717 34.0493363304074,-81.2039934543344 34.0506928740769,-81.2054192170232 34.050078593952,-81.2099213931577 34.0508690665542,-81.2149468443214 34.053171366965,-81.2164251633906 34.0533627435958,-81.2327281067167 34.0566899896514,-81.2422176450282 34.0575395737923,-81.24712734625 34.0609140270607,-81.2545382050741 34.0637625603939,-81.2589193108774 34.0644476936062,-81.2628911280231 34.0676499338974,-81.2753055655994 34.0697056024317,-81.3270196697219 34.0686692309004,-81.3466843193258 34.0840614110054,-81.3531857342342 34.0927203138914,-81.3621294757946 34.1183740796001,-81.3705073441386 34.1540499828205,-81.363900960361 34.165582153094,-81.3486757321992 34.191800021254,-81.3183063425636 34.1807185651098,-81.284687639423 34.1729701142794,-81.2695162932423 34.1668664803039,-81.2262287575511 34.1708461260479,-81.1858135386639 34.1788757373255,-81.1824237132837 34.1772467413441,-81.1675937299667 34.1662163514035,-81.1479878069916 34.1541218440479,-81.1043636910315 34.1585596476097,-81.0764512537223 34.1705473541771,-81.0415761104491 34.1829336843421,-81.0190733056885 34.1953325348687,-80.9598201147065 34.2081351090481,-80.9004906459265 34.2151500917034,-80.8500581449674 34.2214545263054,-80.8629629477818 34.194493890081,-80.8695339477335 34.1829406981548,-80.8648911940733 34.1800976542834,-80.8512674030682 34.1739487025706,-80.8412658987022 34.1660342350919)))'))
```

Are there any functions to take the lines produced from this and create something similar to what is pictured below?

[image]

I've tried utilizing the `st_simplify()` function but it doesn't seem to have any affect on this object.

Comment: You could run concave hull on the lines then run approximateMedialAxis again on the hull polygon